# How Set limit Send request per minute in BeginInvoke on sync c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, synchronization

I have a bulk SMS Soap WebService From One of SMS provider, This web service has Limit 300 requests per minute, If I send more than 300 request, I get a limit error I don't know exactly how to handle requests at BeginInvoke so I don't send requests to the web service for more than 300 minute. How can I implement this restriction in my app by Threading – BeginInvoke? My app is written by C# Asp.net

This is Part of My code for send All request to Oprator Webservice:

```
endCache.SetCacheItem("Success", 0);
                    SendCache.SetCacheItem("Failed", 0);
                    SendCache.SetCacheItem("Invalid", 0);


                    object[] obj = new object[] { MessageID, msgParts, smsPrice, to,from, isUnicode, body };
                    IAsyncResult ar = sendIt.BeginInvoke(sender, to, body, isFlash,ref opCode, MessageID.ToString(), new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), obj);

                    SendCache.SetCacheItem("Result", ar);

private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    string[] opCode = null;

    SendCache.SetCacheItem("Result", ar);


    AsyncResult aResult = (AsyncResult)ar;
    SendSmsDelegate sendIt = (SendSmsDelegate)aResult.AsyncDelegate;
    byte[] retVal = null;


        retVal = sendIt.EndInvoke(ref opCode, ar);
        SendCache.SetCacheItem("Retval", retVal);




    object[] obj = (object[])ar.AsyncState;

    ComputeReceptions((long)obj[0], (int)obj[1], (double)obj[2], (string[])obj[3], retVal, opCode, (long[])obj[4], (int)obj[5], (int)obj[6], (bool)obj[7]);


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches, 1 is send only 5 sms in a second which is odd.Second one is use a queue .Put your sms that you want to send, in a queue and also keep what you sent by time.
Then you can check if you do not pass the limit you pop from that queue and send it.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I can send 300 request to send 100 SMS per request
Do you have Other Solution?
Thank you

Comment: Make a queue (sendingQueue) and put your sms in sending queue instead of send sms directly. Another process reads sendingQueue and pop a message and send it. Where you are reading from sendingQueue you can control sending sms or not. Did you get it?